# In-house app: Unable to download app - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, xcode, in-house-distribution

I have a very tricky problem installing a **.ipa** (**in-house** distribution).
Only on one iPad I cannot install this ipa - while it works in at least other 5 devices - and when I try to install it on that device I get an error "Unable to download app".

Reading the device log while installing I can read:

> MICodeSigningVerifier
>   _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 147: Failed to verify code signature of

Trying to install the ipa on the iPad directly with Xcode i get the error:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
>   [image]

The installation of the ipa through an html page with .plist (in https) works well for all the other devices. I tried also to update iOS to last version (10.3) and after that I tried to reset the device, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in 7 steps:

- registered the device's UDID on the Apple developer portal
- added the device to the development provisioning profile
- downloaded the updated provisioning profile on XCode
- compiled again the .ipa
- installed the .ipa on the device using Xcode
- authorized the developer
- installed the original .ipa from the html page => it worked

I've always had lots of problem due to Apple certificates but this one is the worse ever. Saltassero per aria le mele e i melanisti.

Answer (score 0):

First create Certificate from keychain with these steps

1. Open KeyChain app,
2. Request a certificate from a certificate authority
3. And check Saved to disk & Let me specify key pair information
4. [And save certificat with final step (Check on linked image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJDqr.png)

[After then create your In-house provisioning profile(Check link)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

Comment: you probably didn't read that the app doesn't work only on one device, no problem in others.